# Is there an autocomplete api for google playstore?

Tags: android, api, autocomplete

Is there an autocomplete api for google playstore? I searched google but there hasn't been any reference to that api. I checked in my google's api console, but the only thing I found is the "Google Play Android Developer API" which according to google "the API allows you to check the status of or cancel a user's subscription purchase."
I need this for an android app that I am designing.

Thx!
Rahul.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is the unofficial [Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/), which is not supported by Google. Other than that, no, there is no other API, and there is no official API at all.

So, to answer your question, no, there is no autocomplete API. You may be able to HTTP request the online version of the market, but this would be difficult at best (the requests, the parsing, the... ugh...).

Answer (score 1):

Use this link [https://market.android.com/suggest/SuggRequest?json=1&c=0&query=abc&hl=en&gl=US&callback=*callbacks*._xxx](https://market.android.com/suggest/SuggRequest?json=1&c=0&query=abc&hl=en&gl=US&callback=_callbacks_._xxx)
and replace "abc" with your seed keyword. Example: "cat" or "cat ab", "cat ac"

Comment: What do all parameters mean?